# Get the current language of a device

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Salem alaykom,

I'm working on an automation project. I need to test an Arabic application. First, i need to check the language of the android device. I tried with:

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

But it always give me the English language as result when the language of device is french or Arabic.
Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, `Locale.getDefault()` will return the language setting preferrence the user has enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following instead:

```
Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales();
```

That way you'll see all the available Locales/languages installed. To get the current default one just get the first index of the array returned from the call above:

```
Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0).toString();
```